# Setting the number of columns in a wicket table

Tags: html-table, wicket, repeater

I've been learning wicket 6 over the last few days but although I've looked all over I can't find an answer to this seemingly simple problem.  I have a list of object entities I want to display in an html table.  The table will have a set number of columns and an unknown number of rows.

so

```
List myList=Arrays.asList(obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4)
```

becomes this as an html table:

```
col1  col2  col3

obj1  obj2  obj3
<br>obj4
```

I've experimented with ListView and tried to read up on some wicket repeater classes but examples I've seen all work with a single object entity per table row, with each cell in a row containing an entity field value. In my example I want an entity per cell and be able to define the number of columns so if there are more entities than fit they display on a new row.

Can someone assist me with some appropriate wicket classes that can place elements of a list into a table as above?

Comment: Yeah checkout the wicket 6 docs for GridView its got a little example on them http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/repeater/data/GridView.html

Answer (score 0):

While formulating my first answer I came across the [GridView](http://www.wicketframework.org/wicket-extensions/apidocs/wicket/extensions/markup/html/repeater/data/GridView.html) component. It looks to fit your problem perfectly, but I didn't take a complete look at it yet.